# GAE Chaining Queries through tables

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have these models (below). I want to run a query that gets 10 recent entries from Result  where the "site" ReferenceProperty is one of mine, based on the "users" in Site.

I tried:

```
user = users.get_current_user()
sites = Site.all().filter('user =', user).order('name')
results = Result.all().filter('site IN', sites).fetch(limit=10)
```

The user and sites queries work, but the results one is not working because "sites" is not a list.

```
from google.appengine.ext import db

class Site(db.Model):

users = db.ListProperty(db.Key)
name = db.StringProperty(required=True)
slug = db.TextProperty(required=True)
url = db.TextProperty(required=True)
page = db.TextProperty()
active = db.BooleanProperty()
blackboard = db.BooleanProperty()


class Result(db.Model):

site = db.ReferenceProperty(Site)
timestamp = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
status = db.StringProperty(required=True)
reason = db.StringProperty(required=True)
headers = db.TextProperty()
extra_info = db.TextProperty()
```

Answer (score 3):

Probably because you are not actually executing the sites query; add a .fetch() call, like so:

```
sites = Site.all().filter('user =', user).order('name').fetch(limit=10)
```